# $S_n = x_1^3+x_2^3+ \cdots +x_n^3$ squares perfect

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

It is considered arithmetic progression $x_1,x_2, \cdots, x_n,\cdots, x_1 \neq0$ .
Show that if sums $$S_n = x_1^3+x_2^3+ \cdots +x_n^3$$ is squares perfect for any natural $n \in N$, then there are $k\in N^*$ so $x_n=nk^2$, for any $n \in N$.
All my attempts were fruitless.

Comment: What is $N^*$ ?

Comment: @WiCK3DPOiSON :$N^*$  is the set of integers strictly positive.

Comment: Do we assume that all $x_i \in \mathbb N$?

Comment: I think so, because otherwise we can take $x_1=0$ and $x_{n+1}-x_n=k^2$. For this progression it is easy to see that all $S_n$ are square numbers, but $x_n=(n-1)k^2$ and the problem would be false, say for choosing $k=3$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this helps, but note that $$\sum_{m=1}^{n}{m^3}={(\frac{n(n+1)}2)^2}$$
Setting $x_i=nk^2$ we get
$$S_n=\sum_{m=1}^{n}{(mk^2)^3}=
k^6\sum_{m=1}^{n}{m^3}={(\frac{k^3n(n+1)}2)^2}$$
This is only the converse, however. I have no idea how to proceed for the forward direction.